# Set that is equal to its union

Tags: set-theory

Is there any set $X$ such that $X=\bigcup X$?. I think that there is not any, but I don't know how to prove it, any ideas?

Comment: Talk us through your thought process so far. What work have you done?

Comment: Yes, since $\varnothing=\bigcup\varnothing$.

Comment: Union requires multiple parties (or, in this case, sets) to be an union.

Comment: There are also examples in which $X \neq \varnothing.$ For instance, if $X = \{\varnothing, \; \{\varnothing\},\; \{\{\varnothing\}\},\; \{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}, \; \ldots\}$ then $\bigcup X = X,$ and other possibilities also exist (e.g. do something similar with [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#Definition_as_von_Neumann_ordinals) for the natural numbers).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro: Thank you for this beautiful example for a set $X$ which is not a von Neumann ordinal.

Answer (score 3):

A set $X$ is called *transitive* when $\bigcup X \subseteq X$. So a set equal to its union must be transitive. The condition is equivalent to requiring, for all $x, y$, that if $x\in y\in X$ then $x\in X$; hence the name. Said another way, confining the $y$ quantifier to the antecedent, $X$ is transitive *iff* for all $x$:

$$
(\exists y\in X)\,x\in y \implies x\in X
$$

Conversely, if $X\subseteq \bigcup X$, then every $x\in X$ is a member of some $y\in X$ — the membership relation on $X$ is unbounded upward.

Thus, $X = \bigcup X$ *iff*

$$
(\forall x)\,[
x\in X \iff 
(\exists y\in X)\,x\in y]
$$

Every limit ordinal is an example of such a set.